# The square root of a $3\times3$ matrix has a triple eigenvalue of $1$. Why does it have $4$ similar canonical forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Original exercise:

> A is the square root of $3\times3$ martix, if $A$'s eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ (triple eigenvalue), then how many forms are there in the similar canonical forms of A?
>
> (The answer is $4$.)

Now I know the elementarteiler elementary divisor might be $\lambda-1$, $\lambda-1$, $\lambda-1$, or $
\lambda-1$, $(\lambda-1)^2$, or $(\lambda-1)^3$, thus we can get four forms (in this we consider the sequence of different jordan blocks). My doubt is that why frobenius canonical forms are not considered? Or this exercise is too hasty?

(I'm Chinese and this is the first time I use mathstackexchange. If there are errors in the usage of English or my expression, please forgive me.：) )

Comment: Any Forbenius form is just going to be similar to one of the Jordan forms, so how would they help? But maybe I am not understanding the problem correctly.